Context Load before Client? react-native
i created a context to start up the socket
but before that it validate the token sending a request to the server.
there is an issue that i can't really figure it out.
if the app is closed and i open it i receive this error
ERROR  Error validating token: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getString' of undefined
if i keep the app open, and i Reload the app i see all the logs and data correctly.
i tried setting up a timeout of 1minute since the app opens and i have no errors.
but this approach is not ok.
so i thought the context loaded before the client actually was actually setted up ? no idea
    useEffect(() => {

        const validateToken = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await client.query({
                    query: VALIDATE_TOKEN,
                    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
                });
                console.log('HEREHEREHERE');
                console.log(data);

                if (data && data.ValidateToken) {
                    setSenderID(data.ValidateToken._id);
                    setSenderUserName(data.ValidateToken.userName);
                    setIsTokenValid(true);
                } else {
                    console.error('Token validation failed');
                    setIsTokenValid(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error validating token:', error);
                setIsTokenValid(false);
            }
        };

        validateToken();
    }, []);

import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/cache';
import { storage } from './storage'
import { SERVER } from '@env';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: `http://${SERVER}:5552/graphql` });
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const token = storage.getString('UID');
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    }
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  //uri: 'http://10.0.2.2:5552/graphql',
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
});

export default client


const Root = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <WebSocketProvider>
        <App />
      </WebSocketProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};


